# Pandas Excel groupby/count

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I'm trying to have my script count the number of times it sees the same words in specified columns with some of those columns having multiple separated by a comma.

For example -

```
Labels                        Labs
a1, b3                         1
a2                             3
b3                             1
```

I would want two outputs.

```
Labels  # of labels
a1           1
b3           2


Labels       Lab1     Lab3
a1            1        0
a2            0        1
b3            2        0
```

I was trying to use groupby to count but the only output I am getting in excel is below and I am unable to know what they belong to

```
20
2
1
7
7
```

I have been playing with this but keep getting the same result shown above

```
df1 = df.groupby('Labs').count()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Keys**

1. Convert the comma-separated string into lists first.
2. Use [df.explode()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) to expand the entries.
3. Pivoted aggregation (to which concept that group size belongs) can be achieved by [df.pivot_table()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html).

**Setup**

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""
Labels                        Labs
a1, b3                         1
a2                             3
b3                             1
"""), sep=r"\s{2,}", engine="python")

# split string into list (assume consistent separator pattern)    
df["Labels"] = df["Labels"].str.split(", ")
```

**First output:**

```
df.explode("Labels").groupby("Labels").size()

Out[69]:
Labels
a1    1
a2    1
b3    2
dtype: int64
```

**Second output:**

```
df.explode("Labels").pivot_table(index="Labels", columns="Labs", aggfunc="size")\
    .fillna(0).astype(int)

Out[70]: 
Labs    1  3
Labels      
a1      1  0
a2      0  1
b3      2  0
```

Comment: I'm not able to get those kind of outputs when I try it on my end. The second output in excel comes out as 0 0 1 0 down in a column and repeats a few times in the next columns with some variation of order without saying what the number represent. The first output I get some actual numbers but again it doesn't tell me what the numbers represent.

Comment: Trying to come up with a way to display some of the data so you get a better idea. Most of it is confidential. I'm not sure if this is part of the problem but it looks like while the raw data of the labels are how I displayed it above it looks like part of the process makes it look like this ['a1'] or ['a1,b3'] not sure if that is part of the problem

Comment: Maybe I'm having it do this work in the wrong area? The entire file is a tkinter so I'm using that to choose the file and export out the new version. The first part where it uploads I'm also having it do a lot of work which might be resulting in the bracketed labels and lab names

Comment: Unfortunately the answerer cannot debug on what is not provided. Problems on Excel is also out of the scope of this question. It may be more appropriate to ask a separate question about such side problems (e.g., format conversion, dirty data, I/O with tkinter, etc.). In any case, I believe the logic of these two aggregations are both intact and concise enough to be well-understood.

Comment: So I think I figured out how to put your above recommended in correctly to give me correct information in terms of the count but it's still not telling me what the count is for. So I am using pd.dataframe to try specifying where each piece of data should go it's putting the numbers 130 rows down which is just below the data rather than up in cell 2 for it's column but my other data is all in their corresponding cells. Is there a way to specify where to place the data in pd.dataframe? Sorry for all the questions I'm still very new to programming and self taught