# Groupby not displaying what it is counting

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Hi I'm using groupby to get a count of of each type of label in my data but it is not displaying what the information is and not counting all of the labels.

For reference I am setting this up as a tkinter GUI that uploads a CSV and exports it out as an xlsx with the information broken down. Additionally, I am using pd.dataframe to specify each column with a name. I have a column created with all of the Label types and I am wanting the counts to be displayed with that if possible since it's not wanting to show me which labels it is counting.

To clarify, I get my desired output in my terminal (besides the counting the labels that are 0) but I'm not getting the labels in excel. My output is what I see in excel

Code I'm using

```
 df1 = df.explode('Ticket_Labels').groupby(['Ticket_Labels'])[['Labels']].size()
```

Example of input

```
Ticket_Labels       Labels
   a1, b2             a1
     a1               a2
     a5               a5
   b3, a1             b1
                      b2
                      b3
```

My output

```
 3
 1
 1
 1
```

Desired output

```
 a1   3
 a2   0
 a3   0
 a5   1
 b1   0
 b2   1
 b3   1
```

Update

I also tried using a dataframe when putting into excel.

```
df1 = df.explode('Ticket_Labels').groupby(['Ticket_Labels']).agg({'Labels':'size'})

df3 = pd.DataFrame({'Label':df10, 'Count': df1})

df3.to_excel (r'C:\Users\mcilvn\Desktop\test.xlsx', index = False, header = True)
```

And my output is like the following

```
Label    Count
  a1      ('L', 'a', 'b', 'e', 'l', 's')
  a2      ('L', 'a', 'b', 'e', 'l', 's')
```

Update

Also tried this as I have a total of 25 labels but not all my tickets are utilizing all these labels so I want to fill as 0 for the labels that don't have a ticket.

df10 is just a list of all labels

```
df1 = df.explode('Ticket_Labels').groupby('Ticket_Labels').size().fillna(value = 0)
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'Labels': df10, 'Count': df1})

print (df1)
```

But I get an error that the array length 25 does not match index length 23

Comment: What does output of df.explode('Ticket_Labels') look like ?

Comment: Not sure, it isn't letting me run it by itself. I get ValueError: Shape of passed values in (194, 18), indices imply (158. 18). I get the line from my previous question be answered but they didn't help with why it wasn't giving me the information

Comment: I was able to to get the df.explode to work by itself to see an output. So because I have label values that out as (a1, d3) with the comma it doubles the whole row to be able to separate them.

For example labels (a1, d3) with lab1 being the next column over would make it two rows with a1 and d3 in different rows and both saying lab1 in the next column over

Answer (score 0):

```
 df1 = df.explode('Ticket_Labels').groupby(['Ticket_Labels']).agg({'Labels':'count'})
```

OR

```
 df1 = df.explode('Ticket_Labels').groupby(['Ticket_Labels']).agg({'Labels':'size'})
```

Comment: The second one gave me the same output I was getting before. The count one also gives me just numbers without corresponding label but it gives me incorrect numbers

Comment: I really could use the answer to df.explode('Ticket_Labels')

Comment: Like I said it gives me an error if I try to run it without the rest of the line of code. I also tried running it without the explode portion and I just get a keyerror

Comment: This is my previous question where I was given that answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64974686/pandas-excel-groupby-count

This is what it says df.explode does - https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html

Comment: If I run it without the explode portion I get typerror: unhashable type: list.

I opened my code up into a new file and called the file rather than using a GUI so I can print the output. It appears in the output it will tell me what each label is for but in excel it does not